# Using Excel Drop-Down Menus to Create Dynamic Lookup

Tags: excel

In Excel I have data output from two separate sources, A and B.
Each data set is indentical and consists of 4 columns and several hundred rows. At the end of each row is a total, which is the only variable between souces A and B

Something like this, just for illustration.

Source A 

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Total

AB  CD  EF  GH  1234

IJ  KL  MN  OP  4567

QR  ST  UV  WX  7890

Source B 

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Total 

AB  CD  EF  GH  1338

IJ  KL  MN  OP  4599

QR  ST  UV  WX  7999

I need to reconcile the data sources. 
What I would like to do is use a drop down list to select the column permutations, and then print the total for each source.
So when I select from the dropdown the combination

AB > CD > EF > GH - Source A = 1234
         - Source B = 1338

Or

IJ > KL > MN > OP - Source A = 4567
           - Source B = 4599

I just want to know if these is possible and where to start.
I apologise in advance for my awful HTML formtating and would really appreciate your input.

Regards

Comment: Do you just want to consolidate those two tables into one table with 6 columns: Col 1 - Col 2 - Col 3 - Col 4 - Total A - Total B ?  And to do that, you need to perform a lookup on the 4 columns as if they were one?

Comment: Hi and thanks, I guess that would work but I didn't want to use that approach just in case there were any undetected differences in the values in the columns, if that follows.

Comment: At this stage I would be willing to at least try that however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the four column values in both Source A and Source B are in the same order, you can create a "key" in both tables by concatenating values for each row.

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2  -> ABCDEFGH
```

Then in your source A Table, lookup values from your source B table using that key.

Comment: Thanks, that hasn't worked. I'm ensuring the values in sources A and B are identical and concatenating (though I'm using & because those values are actually integer strings) and I'm getting the #VALUE error for every single lookup. This is frustrating because I know there should be matches throughout due to having spent ages manually checking for matches.

Comment: How are you concatenating the integer strings?  You can add a '-' or other symbol in between the integers so that the resultant key is definitely a text string and not an integer.  Sorry if I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: can you paste your lookup formula?

Comment: =vlookup([unique ID in Source A],[table range incl Unique ID of source B],[column no of Total],FALSE)

Comment: Does that help? Tried to illustrate what I'm referencing in lookup.